# Extract part of command output to use in another command

Tags: windows, command-line, ms-dos

Using Windows command prompt, I want to unlock and delete several files in a single command if possible. So far I have managed to come up with:

```
net file | findstr /R [0-9]*lock
```

This results in:

```
12345 C:\MyProgram\0001.lock user.name 0
12346 C:\MyProgram\0002.lock user.name 0
12347 C:\MyProgram\0003.lock user.name 0
12348 C:\MyProgram\0004.lock user.name 0
12349 C:\MyProgram\0005.lock user.name 0
```

The first part of the string (ID) would be used as follows:

```
net file 12345 /close
```

The second part of the string (path) would be used as follows:

```
del C:\MyProgram\0001.lock
```

I would like to put this into a batch script, which would cycle through each line ouputted by findstr, grab the 1st and 2nd parts and execute the commands accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sort of thing is much easier with a Unix shell and tools like sed on Windows.  Is that an option for you or do you need this done using only the stuff that ships with Windows?

Comment: Check out the help for the **for** command. The default space and tab *delims* will split the strings, and *tokens* can be used to retrieve only the first two portions that you're after.

Comment: Thanks Karan, this worked best for me. If you could post this as an answer, I'll give you the points. :)